# record.factory is not a function error on Angular Javascript page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When compiling my app and runnning, the HTML page displays as blank and will not show the app. I was able to use the Inspect tool on Google Chrome and Chrome is saying that **record.factory is not a function**, the page was working fine. However, I did recently update my angular version to the latest - so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Here's my module.ts code, I suspect it's something with the Imports, usually that has been the case when I run into issues with the app not displaying:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { ItemService } from './items.service';
import { NewItemFormComponent } from './new-item-form/new-item-form.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'; 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { AutofillMonitor } from '@angular/cdk/text-field';
import { ContentObserver } from '@angular/cdk/observers';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewItemFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ItemService, Platform, BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule, AutofillMonitor, ContentObserver],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you should include those modules inside providers section? I think no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar error, [this comment's post](https://github.com/vendure-ecommerce/vendure/issues/758#issuecomment-799292518) helped me. It happens when you use packages compiled in different Angular versions:

> "Packages must be compiled and ran using the exact same version of
> Angular; any other combination is not supported and likely to break in
> subtle ways."

Comment: If what you say is correct, than how do ppl create frameworks that support multiple versions?

Comment: @hackp0int , sorry but I didn't understand: what do you mean with "ppl"?

Comment: Ppl = people :) sorry.

Comment: OK :) I don't know how to support multiple frameworks. In my case, I maintain libraries and projects, so I'm able to align versions between different packages.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove modules from **providers** array.
Remove:
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment

> @Injectable() in your routing or injecting else

Example

```
//   @Injectable()  comment this code

 @NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [] 
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the service from your provider list. I had the same issue and was resolved when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm having is after upgrading from 9 to 11, but @Injectable wasn't automatically added to app.module.ts when I upgraded. My problem does not seem to be caused by @Injectable.

This [comment](https://github.com/vendure-ecommerce/vendure/issues/758#issuecomment-799281578) helped me a lot, I had this problem when I verified all @angular packages version 11.0.0, using the version in this list will fix it.

```
├─ @angular/animations@11.2.4
├─ @angular/cdk@11.2.3
├─ @angular/cdk@11.2.3
├─ @angular/cdk@11.2.3
├─ @angular/cli@11.2.3
├─ @angular/common@11.2.4
├─ @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.4
├─ @angular/compiler@11.2.4
├─ @angular/core@11.2.4
├─ @angular/forms@11.2.4
├─ @angular/language-service@11.2.4
├─ @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.4
├─ @angular/platform-browser@11.2.4
└─ @angular/router@11.2.4
```